# How to stretch text in the textblock

Tags: wpf

How to stretch text in textblock the same like in UWP using TextLineBounds

[UWP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGbpa.png)

```
    <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
        <TextBlock Foreground="Black" TextLineBounds="Tight">
            123
        </TextBlock>
    </Viewbox>
```

In WPF

[WPF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O996Y.png)

```
    <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
        <TextBlock Foreground="Black">
            123
        </TextBlock>
    </Viewbox>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text stretch in WPF TextBlock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282134/text-stretch-in-wpf-textblock)

Comment: In WPF not working TextLineBounds, this is my problem.

Comment: I looking for something like a TextLineBounds just in WPF